# VLOOKUP formula in VBA for same cell every sheet

Tags: vba, for-loop, vlookup

I'm trying to make a simple macro in VBA to change the name the formula of a same cell in all worksheets in a workbook. However, for some reason it doesnt work. Can someone explain to me what is wrong? Why does it work to change the formula to lookupvalue but not to formulavalue?

```
Sub RenameTest()

For Each aSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    aSheet.Activate
    If aSheet.Name <> "Test" Then
        Dim lookupvalue As String
        Dim formulavalue As String
        lookupvalue = Cells(2, 3).Value
        formulavalue = "=VLOOKUP(" & lookupvalue & "'Test'!A1:B122;2;FALSE)"
        Cells(2, 11).Formula = formulavalue
    End If


Next aSheet
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.Formula` property you should always use comma `,` as separator (even if your local settings required semicolon as separator). Change `;` to `,` :

```
formulavalue = "=VLOOKUP(" & lookupvalue & ",'Test'!A1:B122,2,FALSE)"
Cells(2, 11).Formula = formulavalue
```

Alternatively, you could use `.FormulaLocal` (with your local separator, i.e. semicolon `;`):

```
formulavalue = "=VLOOKUP(" & lookupvalue & ";'Test'!A1:B122;2;FALSE)"
Cells(2, 11).FormulaLocal = formulavalue
```

another issue - you've missed comma (semicolon) before `'Test'!A1:B122`.

Comment: Still "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: At least the formula ends up in the cells. However, it wants me to add " " around lookup value, but I get the error when I try to add this. How can I do this? I get the error when I try & CHR(34) & etc.

Comment: `However, it wants me to add " " around lookup value,` - sorry, don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: @GoodGuyMike, try my updated answer - you've missed `,` before `'Test'!A1:B122`

Comment: How could I change so that the loop starts on sheet n rather than skipping the sheet called "Test"?

Comment: change `For each..` to `For i = n to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`. Next line: `Set aSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)`